# xampp mysql Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: YES

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm stuck to this error. I don't have a password for the root, but still getting this one. Please help me, do check the screenshot I'm going to provide..

[image]

Comment: So what is the question? You need to reset the password?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537531/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no?rq=1

Comment: Check this out: http://tinypic.com/r/152mkp4/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the password is specified and it is wrong. Check it on your php page, where connection string or password is set.

Comment: From the stack you can see that error was thrown from the php application. You should find it yourself. It is the place where application stores connection string or password.