# Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'(using password:NO)

Tags: mysql

I get the following error message when I use the "mysqladmin version" command.

MYSQLADMIN: connect to server 'localhost' failed
 error: 'Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'(using password:NO)'

How can I connect to server 'localhost'?

Comment: Did you google your problem? hope this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537531/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no or http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=276342

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. We are here to help you and we are no human search bots.... Question `How can I go about finding a solution to this problem?` Maybe read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)