# MySQL unable to reset 'root' password

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora-21

I have tried to follow all the suggestions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html) but none worked for me. I have installed mysql community server on Fedora `mysql-community-server-5.7.9-1.fc21.x86_64`

I have tried to access the temporary password using 
`sudo grep 'temporary password' mysqld.log` but it does not return any password.

I keep getting error 
`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I get this error when i execute mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

`2016-06-14 10:46:00 3495 mysqld_safe: Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
chown: invalid user: ‘@MYSQLD_USER@’
2016-06-14 10:46:00 3495 mysqld_safe: The file @libexecdir@/mysqld
does not exist or is not executable. Please cd to the mysql installation
directory and restart this script from there as follows:
./bin/mysqld_safe&
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/mysqld-safe.html for more information`

I am not able to reset the root user password. Please help.

Comment: have you tried accessing without a password?   `mysql -uroot`

Comment: Also, see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19229842/1911755

Answer (score 3):

For mysql 5.7 on centos

```
systemctl stop mysqld
systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"
systemctl start mysqld
mysql -u root
mysql> use mysql; 
mysql> update user set authentication_string=password('you new pass') where 
user='root';
mysql> flush privileges; 
mysql> exit

systemctl restart mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

RESET MYSQL ROOT PASSWORD( for linux users)

## Login to root user and run

```
Step 1# /etc/init.d/mysql stop 
Step 2# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & 
Output : Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql mysqld_safe[6025]: started

Step 3 Login to new terminal (with root user)
    
   [#] mysql -u root

mysql> use mysql; 
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD('NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD') where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges; 
mysql> quit

Step 4 # Stop MySQL Server:

/etc/init.d/mysql stop

Step 5 # /etc/init.d/mysql start

mysql -u root -pNEWPASSWORD
```

--------------------- completed----------

Comment: This isn't "recovering" the password; it's just setting one where one didn't exist. The step "Login to new terminal (with root user)" is not going to work if the root user has an unknown password.

Comment: You may need to login root user of your linux machine then you will able to get access of all mysql commands