# mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Guys i'm having common issue.
I want to display data from MySQL database into HTML page using PHP.

Using this code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Pulse Sensor Data </title>

</head>
<body>

<?php

$servername = 'localhost'; 
$username = 'root';  
$password = '';

// Connect to database server
mysql_connect('192.168.1.106','root','','database') or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db('database') or die(mysql_error());

// SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM pulsesensor";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

   // Write the value of the column id and value
  echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['value'] . "<br />";

  }

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

but i got

> mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'XXX' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\html.php on line 16
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'Dell' (using password: NO)

i changed the password the same error appear

> mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'XXX' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\html.php on line 16
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'Dell' (using password: YES)

i don't know what to do

Comment: so why did you assign this `$servername = 'localhost';` and using `192.168.1.106` after?

Comment: You need to stop using `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated for years and don't even exist in current PHP releases. Please study about [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php), commonly referred as PDO for short.

Comment: possible duplicateof http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537531/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no

Comment: Is `192.168.1.106` the local computer's IP address? If not, you need to grant permission to connect from your IP on the MySQL server. You should also create a user to use to connect with. Using root/administrator accounts should only be done when you actually need to.

Comment: You are connecting to `Dell`, `localhost`, or `192.168.1.106`?

Comment: ops never notice that :/ i tried to make it access remotely so i used my IP address instead of localhost  >> its worked when i changed the IP into localhost  but i want it to access remotely

Comment: The PHP connecting is remote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow remote connection to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Comment: thanks for you suggestion i'll read it @sidyll

Comment: yes it is .. so i have to create another user instead the root and use it @Mike

Comment: i make static IP for further step cause i want to access remotely that's the why i used 192.168.1.106 but it still local @chris85

Comment: @TabarekGhassan You need to forward port 3360 from your router to the static IP of your server in order to allow remote connections.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is using the ip address and root is not configured to access via the ip address you are using for the host. You will have to change it to **localhost** or add that permission to your mysql server for the root user.

I would suggest that you not do that, but create a new mysql user for your development.

Also, from @sidyll you will not want to use the `mysql_*` functions and use **PDO** functions instead.

Comment: thanks a  lot its worked but in localhost environment but if i want to make it remotely is the new user will help me in this case?.. sorry for these questions its my first experiment  @srayhunter

Comment: That is correct. I would recommend creating a new user that is for this project's database and tables. Then you can restrict the new user's access to the database and tables for the project. I would recommend researching mysql users and how access and permissions work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
mysql_connect($servername,'root','','database') or die (mysql_error ());
```

Comment: Answer should have explanations.