# how to find mysql 5.7 root password osx

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

I have installed **MySQL Community Server 5.7.17** and I'm using **macOS Sierra 10.12.3**. When I installed it, mysql didn't noticed me what is root password, when i try to login with `mysql -uroot` it says:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO).

Where I can find temporary mysql password?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19229842/7397002)

Comment: I doubt you can find it. You'll have to reset it.